# How can I create a file on SD card in C using NXP processor?

Tags: c, sd-card, nxp-microcontroller

I can use functions in C that write/read data from SD card, using LPC54616. This functions are able to modifiy each byte in the card. But if I insert card to the computer, I can't view stored data. So I need to save them to *.txt file (for example) and view them. How can I create text file on SD card in C using NXP processor?

Thank you for your response.

Comment: If you can already read and write raw data on SD card storage, then you only need file system layer. You need to write it, or use library. For example, for FAT32 file system you could try to use FatFS library. But, if you can already read SD card, it means that you probably have already some SD card driver. It might already be bundled with file system library.

Comment: Yes, FatFS library is what i was looking for. Thank you!